# Create Report in an array from AD users and attributes, and allow attributes to be blank

Tags: active-directory

I created a fairly simple script to do some reporting for HR a while back.  It basically grabs users from active directory and puts it into an array that HR uses for reporting of users with attributes like first name, last name, email, manager ,etc.  Nothing too special.

What i'm finding is that certain fields like Manager are not used very often and when that's the case the array will end up using the previous person's attributes rather than allow the attribute to be blank.  What can I input to allow blanks for users and not use the previous person's attributes?  Here is rough idea of the code...

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -filter * -properties sAMAccountname, givenName, surname, Title, Manager

$Array =[System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

Foreach ($User in $Users){

    $match = New-Object PSObject
        $match | Add-Member NoteProperty "User Name" $User.sAMAccountname
        $match | Add-Member NoteProperty "First Name" $User.givenName
        $match | Add-Member NoteProperty "Last Name" $User.surname
        $match | Add-Member NoteProperty "Title" $User.Title
        $match | Add-Member NoteProperty "Manager" $User.Manager
        $Array += $match
        }
$Array | Export-csv -path C:\temp\Users.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The output works just fine, minus when the last person in AD doesn't have something filled in and here it's usually manager.  like shown below.  So it just retains the manager value and uses on the next line.

sAMAccountName   - givenName  -  surname  -   Title        -         Manager

123456           -    Tom    -     Burke     -  Head of sales     -  8805488

456789     -       Ken     -    Grady   -    Sales Ops Manager  -   8805488

When that last user 456789 doesn't have manager filled in AD.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Solved...

I input a sleep period as it would appear that slowing things down a bit helped clear the variable for the array.  I also input a clear-variable match at the beginning to ensure it was cleared of old data moving forward.